# Where does psql import import to?

Tags: sql, postgresql, import, psql

I got a SQL dump file and try to import it into my database with the following command:

```
psql -U postgres timetable  < /tmp/restores/2\ Restore\ Rooms.sql
```

It contains several SET commands, a CREATE TABLE timetable.rooms and several other commands.
I logged in via `psql -U postgres` before and created the schema timetable and ran the above import command, but it returned some errors. So I logged back in and dropped the schema timetable to start again. After that the import returned the following:

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ psql -U postgres timetable  < /tmp/restores/2\ Restore\ Rooms.sql 
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config 
------------
 
(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  relation "rooms" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  relation "rooms_id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rooms_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(50) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY rooms, line 1
 setval 
--------
     57
(1 row)

ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "rooms" are not allowed
postgres@ubuntu:~$ psql -U postgres
psql (12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.
```

I then tried to access the table timetable.rooms but it wasn't there:

```
postgres=# select * from 
information_schema.  pg_catalog.          pg_temp_1.           pg_toast.            pg_toast_temp_1.     public.
```

Where did it import the tables then and how do I access it, if not via `psql -U postgres`?

Comment: Well, your `psql -U postgres timetable` connected to database `timetable` and restored the dump there, while your interactive session is obviously connected to database `postgres`. It is unsurprising that the data are not there.

Comment: Thanks.. I obviously did not understand what database it connects to if I leave out a specific name.